# polymorphism child list in parent list

Tags: c#, list, polymorphism

I have this base class and i created a list of Media ( List)

```
public abstract class Media 
{

    #region Fields

    private DateTime? _releaseDate;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public Media() 
    {

    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    //Used to convert the Json propertyname
    [Key]
    public int MediaId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int ApiId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
    [MaxLength(200), MinLength(0)]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "overview")]
    [MaxLength(10000), MinLength(0)]
    public string Plot { get; set; }


    //Todo definer lengths
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "poster_path")]
    [MaxLength(200), MinLength(0)]
    public string Image { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]
    [MaxLength(30), MinLength(0)]
    public string Status { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "release_date")]
    public virtual DateTime? ReleaseDate 
    { 
        get { return _releaseDate; }
        set 
        {
            _releaseDate = value;
        }

    }

    public int TotaltRating { get; set; }
    public int AmountOfRaters { get; set; }
    public double CurrentRating { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "genres")]
    public virtual List<Genre> GenresInMedia { get; set; }


    public virtual List<Actor> ActorsInMedia { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Tag> TagsInMedia { get; set; }


    public virtual List<Reviewer> SeenBy { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Then i have this subclass ( I also have some other subclasses, but haven't pasted them here)

```
public class Movie : Media
{

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "budget")]
    public int Budget { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tagline")]
    [MaxLength(1000), MinLength(0)]
    public string Tagline { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<Trailer> Trailers { get; set; }

}
```

This is code i try to implement.

```
List<Media> MediaList = new List<Media>();
List<Movie> MovieList = new List<Movie>();
MovieList.Add(new Movie());
MovieList.Add(new Movie());
MovieList.Add(new Movie());

MediaList.AddRange(MovieList);
```

This gives me an NullReferenceException

```
MediaList.AddRange(MovieList.Cast<Media>().ToList());
```

This also gives me an NullReferenceException..

How can i cast a list of Movies to a list of Media? It doesn't seem to work..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like the json properties have nothing to do with your problem. Try and post a more concise version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something else going on.  I copied your code and ran this...

```
public abstract class Media
{
    #region Fields

    private DateTime? _releaseDate;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public Media() 
    {

    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    //Used to convert the Json propertyname
    [Key]
    public int MediaId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int ApiId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
    [MaxLength(200), MinLength(0)]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "overview")]
    [MaxLength(10000), MinLength(0)]
    public string Plot { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public class Movie : Media
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "budget")]
    public int Budget { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tagline")]
    [MaxLength(1000), MinLength(0)]
    public string Tagline { get; set; }

    //[NotMapped]
    //public List<Trailer> Trailers { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
List<Media> MediaList = new List<Media>();
List<Movie> MovieList = new List<Movie>();
MovieList.Add(new Movie());
MovieList.Add(new Movie());
MovieList.Add(new Movie());

MediaList.AddRange(MovieList);

MediaList.AddRange(MovieList.Cast<Media>().ToList());
```

It worked fine.  MediaList has 6 elements in it.

I had to comment out Trailer since you didn't provide that.